# Why is the space between the IconButtons not filled?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

I am writing an app in flutter right now and I wanted to make a custom AppBar. I chose two IconButtons, put them into a row, and tried to fill the space between them. Somehow nothing happens and they stay in the same place. I would like one IconButton to be on the left and the other one on the right.

Here is my code:

```
    class TopNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
      const TopNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_rounded,
              ),
              iconSize: 40.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.all_inbox_rounded,
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              iconSize: 40.0,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Here an image, that shows how it looks like right now:
[image: Screenshot]

When I run this Code by basudev nayak, it gives me errors:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: Row(
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    TopNavigator(),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class TopNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
      const TopNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_rounded,
              ),
              iconSize: 40.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            Spacer(),
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.all_inbox_rounded,
              ),
              iconSize: 40.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
    

Errors: 
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#e3531 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Scaffold file:///C:/Users/Eugen/Desktop/FlutterProjects/eduhub/lib/main.dart:9:13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Null check operator used on a null value
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Row file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/FlutterProjects/eduhub/lib/main.dart:11:15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Try a Spacer() widget between them in the row. Also, I suggest this article for a bit of layout background info: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Expanded` 
code snippet

```
body: Row(
      children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TopNavigator(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TopNavigator(),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.add_rounded,
          ),
          iconSize: 40.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Spacer(),
        IconButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.all_inbox_rounded,
          ),
          iconSize: 40.0,
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TopNavigator({Key key}) : super(key: key);@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.add_rounded,
      ),
      iconSize: 40.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {},
    ),Spacer(),
    IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.all_inbox_rounded,
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      iconSize: 40.0,
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ],
);}}
```

This should do the job .

Comment: When I run the code, I get 2 errors. I have added them in the question

Comment: You've put a row inside of a column then you are using a custom widget which returns a row , I think this is the reason you're getting this error . Try nesting less row and column and try again .

Comment: Look row and column generally have a tendency to put everything to the side , think of it like a box inside a box of another box . The first row is putting the column inside it to the left cause there is no main and cross axis alignment specified. Hope you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

For alignment of elements in Row or Column widget, use MainAxisAlignment and CrossAxisAlignment. For more information, you can read the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#aligning-widgets).

For your case, you want 2 icons to be apart from each other in the main axis of Row, so you need to specify MainAxisAlignment property, which should be:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
)
```

For the error, you can wrap your Row in a Container and set width for it. [Here](https://codepen.io/dungngo96/pen/ZEpEEax) a code snippet.

Also, for this part

```
body: Row(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        TopNavigator(),
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

I don't think you need Row and Column here. Just set

```
body: TopNavigator()
```

and it'll still work fine

Answer (score 0):

use Spacer() widget between the two iconButtons